# How do I access information about the currently running test case from the beforeEach function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, automated-tests, jasmine2.0

Using Protractor 5.1.2 and Jasmine2 for describing test cases, how does one get the current testcase/spec being run in the beforeEach method?

I would like to do some different setup based on which test case I'm running.  I do not want to put these tests in different spec files with repeating code except for the little bit I want to change in the setup.

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
...
beforeEach(() => {
  if(currentSpec/TestCase.name == "thisName") {
    // Do a particular login specific to testcase.name
  } else { 
    // Do a default login
  }
});
...
```

My research into this brought up much older solutions (2+ years) that are very out of date and seem to keep saying that accessing the currently running testcase/spec is something they (protractor) try to keep hidden.  I feel like wanting to do particular setup for a particular test case in a suite of test cases is not a unique thing.  I could just be using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to do what you want with `beforeEach()`. But, I think you can get the same effect by using a helper file. This will allow you to setup a common file that any spec can reference so you can use a common set of functions. To set this up, you will:

Create a central file (I call mine `util.js`)

```
const helper = function(){
    this.exampleFunction = function(num){
        return num; //insert function here
    }
    this.exampleFunction2 = function(elem){
        elem.click() //insert function here
    } 
}
```

Inside your `spec.js` file you will do:

```
const help = require('path/to/util.js');
const util = new help();
describe('Example with util',function(){
    it('Should use util to click an element',function(){
        let elem = $('div.yourItem');
        util.exampleFunction2(elem);
    });
});
```

You can then call these functions from any spec file. You would then be able to seperate your tests into seperate spec files, but have a common set of functions for the parts that are the same.

Another way to do this, without creating separate files is to just use a local function.
Example `spec.js` file:

```
describe('Should use functions',function(){
    afterEach(function(){
        $('button.logout').click();
    )};
    it('Should run test as user 1',function(){
        $('#Username').sendKeys('User1');
        $('#Password').sendKeys('Password1');
        $('button.login).click();
        doStuff();
    )};
    it('Should run test as user 2',function(){
        $('#Username').sendKeys('User2');
        $('#Password').sendKeys('Password2');
        $('button.login').click();
        doStuff();
    )};
    function doStuff(){
        $('div.thing1').click();
        $('div.thing2').click();
    )};
)};
```

As per comments for multiple describes:

```
describe('Test with user 1',function(){   
   beforeEach(function(){
       //login as user 1
   });
   it('Should do a thing',function(){
       //does the thing as user 1
   });
});
describe('Test with user 2',function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        //login as user 2
    });
    it('Should do another thing',function(){
        //does the other thing as user 2
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a good example of a helper file and pulling it in, so thank you for that.  But I think I explained my question badly, because I was looking for a way to access the instance of the test itself from my beforeEach method.  Thank you though!

Comment: @S.Huston Thanks, as far as I know, `beforeEach` can't do what you are describing. It is allowed for there to be multiple `describes` in a single spec file so maybe check that out, it might be useful to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you have a beforeEach nested within describes? I'm fuzzy on the connection there. I know you can have describes nested.

Comment: Haha! Tested and it works, and the logic works much better too. Thank you for the direction I needed.  If you could write this up, nesting beforeEachs within particular describes, that would be the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @S.Huston you mentioned that you want to access the currently running testcase. `beforeEach` runs **before** the testcase so the test that will run after it is unknown to it. The second part of my answer might help more, as it's not using helper files. Even if there **IS** a way to do this with `beforeEach` or nested loops, it is likely more complicated than needed, and using functions would be much easier

Comment: @S.Huston edited answer to include nested loops. For future, it would probably be best to split into separate files, but if it works it works

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `beforeEach` is that it is the **same** for each test.

If you want to do different things, then they belong in the specific test.

Write a helper function and call it from the specific test if you want to have common functionality that does slightly different things depending on an argument.

Comment: I get your point of it being the same, and it mostly is.  Except for the login.  One uses a default login info, the other uses a different status of user, but the rest of the setup is the same after that, just need a different token. So it's like I had A->B->C->D. Then I split A into A1 and A2.  I wanted to leave B->D the same. In the same place, beforeEach, for logic's sake. Ignoring coding ideals, is there not a way to access information about the currently running testcase?